# xpath identifying a value in the middle of the path by criteria from later in the path

Tags: xml, xpath

So I have a set of XML that looks something like:

```
<root>
  <trunk>
    <branch>
      <name>Object</name>
      <state>OK</status>
      <details>
        <detail>
          <type>ABC</type>
          <location>Alpha</location>
        </detail>
      </details>
    </branch>
    <branch>
      <name>Object</name>
      <state>OK</status>
      <details>
        <detail>
          <type>ABC</type>
          <location>Beta</location>
        </detail>
      </details>
    </branch>
  </trunk>
</root>
```

If I do the following Xpath:

```
contains(/root/trunk/branch[name='Object']/state,'OK')
```

I will get two responses. As a result, I can't do any further Xpath logic, like:

```
contains(/root/trunk/branch[name='Object']/state,'OK') and contains(/root/trunk/branch[name='Object']/details/detail/location, 'Alpha')
```

If I do, I get the error:

```
"Unable to perform XPath operation. A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of contains() ('Alpha','Beta')"
```

*Note: The above logic works just fine if there is only one branch with the name 'Object'.*

I did some digging around and found the concept of Axis that might let me navigate around, but I can't quite wrap my head around the explanation enough to turn that into some kind of syntax and the examples I've found so far aren't quite in the same realm of complexity that I'm stuck with.

I'll admit that I'm stumbling through this a bit blind as this is only my second exposure to mucking about with XML data, so I may be asking the question wrong or even looking at the problem entirely wrong.

My environment is basically JavaScript with an imported package that can execute Xpath statements. Ideally, I'd like to do this as a single Xpath statement if that is feasible, but I accept that my expectations might be too high.

The end goal is to return the current *state* of the **Object** with *location* **Alpha**.

I cannot change any of the XML structure or data within that structure. This is a Rest API call to a system health function of a software product I've installed.

I appreciate any assistance or direction to a learning resource with examples that might help me get across the finish line. I've been googling, but I'm not sure that I understand enough of what I'm trying to do it put in terms that will return the results I am looking for.

Comment: Hi J.V. Your XML is not well-formed. Please edit your original post and fix the XML.

Comment: Is our desired out just `OK`; or something else?

Comment: @Yitzhak Khabinsky While the contents are obfuscated for confidentiality reasons and trimmed for brevity, it is literally the exact xml style that I am faced with. I appreciate your time in reviewing my question.

Comment: @Jack Fleeting Any variation of that is fine. I can add /text() to get just the text or do a pattern match. Someone has provided me with the answer I was looking for though, so thank you for reviewing my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The end goal is to return the current state of the Object with location Alpha.*

This XPath expression

```
/root/trunk/branch[name='Object'][details/detail/location='Alpha']/state
```

Selects:

```
<state>OK</state>
```

Test in [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/35136c8b7d048200cba08a70a33b714e)

Comment: Brilliant and so simple. I was definitely over-complicating it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do note that I have kept the `[name='Object']` predicate because I don't know if there are others type of `branch` element.

Comment: In my scenario, everything is a ```branch```. It is only the details within those containers that differ.